# The prefix "fx" for element "fx:deploy" is not bound

Tags: java, netbeans, exe

I'm trying to make EXE package of my application in Java NetBeans
But, this message appears in build.xml when I click Clean and Build ….
How to solve it?

```
<project name="bra" default="default" basedir=".">
<description>Builds, tests, and runs the project bra.</description>
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
    <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" 
       nativeBundles="all"
       outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">

        <fx:application name="${application.title}" 
              mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}"  vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>          
 </target>
 </project>
```

Comment: Define the `fx` namespace in your XML.

Comment: how?? @Henry can you clarify more? I'm not good in XML

Answer (score 1):

finally done..!!
 just edit this line :

```
<project name="bra" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
```

to define **fx** namespace